# How did Tina Goldstein regain her consciousness?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

Tina Goldstein lost her consciousness when the executioner lady took something out of her head.

[image]

But later, she regained her consciousness:

[image]

How did Tina regain her consciousness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Tina “woke up” because she was no longer “sedated” by good memories.

The reason Tina was calm was because the pool of death potion had been playing her good memories, making it seem warm and enticing. Then they start turning to bad memories as Newt fights back.

> “*PICKETT clambers onto EXECUTIONER 2’S arm and bites, startling and distracting her, giving NEWT time to grab her arms and take aim with her wand. A spell fires, hitting EXECUTIONER 1, who drops to the floor, her wand falling into the pool. As it falls, the liquid rises up in viscous black bubbles, instantly engulfing the wand.
> In reaction, TINA’S memories turn from good to bad: we see MARY LOU, pointing aggressively at TINA.*
>
> MARY LOU
>
> Witch!
>
> *TINA, still enraptured by the pool, looks increasingly terrified. Her chair is lowering closer and closer to the liquid.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

Then the memories stop entirely and she “wakes up” from the state they had induced.

> “TINA snaps out of her reverie and screams.
>
> TINA
>
> MR SCAMANDER!
>
> *The liquid has now turned into a black bubbling death potion. It rises up, surrounding TINA on her chair. TINA stands up to get away, almost falling off in her haste. She tries desperately to regain her balance.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>